# Center of gravity of vehicle and vehicle performance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, everyday-life

I am interested to know how does [CG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) of vehicle plays role in the Fuel economy and the vehicle performance. Does CG of vehicle has anything to do while accelerating of your vehicle. I am a student, henceforth I would feel glad to know about these issues. Can any one give me the link that containing these topics.

Comment: Hi Ajay, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! What is it exactly that you want to know? Are you asking whether the position of a car's center of gravity affects its fuel economy?

Comment: I think you need to specify the conditions under which you are interested in examining. Flat road, incline, steady speed, normal driving, ...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Wikipedia article on [handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_handling). This article strikes me as less than 100% rigorous, but it gives a good general description of the issues involved. In brief, the higher the centre of mass the greater the moment of force rotating the vehicle. When cornering this moment causes the car to lean and lose grip on the inside tyres.

Answer (score 1):

The CG location fore-aft as well as height has primary effect on performance and secondary effect on fuel economy. The CG location determines the balance of forces on the tires under acceleration, cruise, or deceleration. The primary effect is that the balance of forces affects traction. The more weight over a tire the more the traction of that tire.

The secondary effect is that tires a non-linear and the more load you put on them the more inefficient they become. Weight distributed evenly among all tires yields the most efficient condition.

In addition, a centralized CG location yields the minimum yaw moment of inertia making it easier for a car to change direction.